# Detect multiple drop-down selections and paragraph content dynamically with jQuery and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a madlib style paragraph with multiple drop-down selections for synonyms of various words. Here's an example:

```
<p id="the-text">This is an example paragraph containing many
    <select class="selector">
        <option>selections</option>
        <option>dropdown thingies</option>
        <option>option choosers</option>
    </select>that I would like to be able to
    <select class="selector">
        <option>click on</option>
        <option>select</option>
        <option>choose</option>
    </select>and then know what the
    <select class="selector">
        <option>final</option>
        <option>selected</option>
        <option>variable</option>
    </select>paragraph text is.
    <select class="selector">
        <option>It would be great</option>
        <option>It would be nice</option>
        <option>It'd be delightful</option>
    </select>, and
    <select class="selector">
        <option>useful</option>
        <option>helpful</option>
        <option>interesting</option>
    </select>to dynamically create paragraphs like this.</p>
<textarea id="text-area" rows="4" cols="110">This is where the text should appear...     
</textarea>
```

Here is a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/T4guG/2/

Using jQuery and Javascript, I am trying to get the selected (and surrounding) text to appear in the text area.

It's kind of working, but there are two problems:

1) SOLVED: There was a problem with punctuation, but replacing:

```
    if (element == "{") {
        content_array[i] = foo[j];
        j++;
    }
```

with

```
    if (element.indexOf('{') >= 0) {
        content_array[i] = foo[j];
        j++;
    }
```

allows { to be detected consistently

2) SOLVED: you only can change the options once.

Is there a more elegant solution than what I have come up with? Here is the code:

```
function updateTextArea() {
    //get all of the text selections, and put them in an array
    var foo = [];
    $('.selector :selected').each(function (i, selected) {
        foo[i] = $(selected).text();
    });

    //get the paragraph content, and store it
    var safe_content = $('#the-text').html();

    //delete all the options
    $('.selector').text('');

    //get the text without the dropdown options
    var content = $('#the-text').html();

    //create a regex expression to detect the remaining drop-down code
    var pattern = "<select class=\"selector\"></select>",
        re = new RegExp(pattern, "g");

    //replace all the drop-down selections with {
    content = content.replace(re, "{");

    //turn the content into an array
    content_array = content.split(" ");

    //go through the array, and if a element is {, go to "foo" and replace it with the selected option
    var length = content_array.length,
        element = null;
    var j = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        element = content_array[i];

        if (element == "{") {
            content_array[i] = foo[j];
            j++;
        }

    }

    //turn the array back into a paragraph
    new_content = content_array.join(" ");

    //replace the text with the origionanl text
    $('#the-text').html(safe_content);

    //put the new content into the text area
    $('#text-area').val(new_content);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    updateTextArea();
});

$(".selector").change(function () {
    updateTextArea();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are splitting text based on `" " (using space)` and replacing element `{` with `array` value but  `text is. {, and` contains comma i.e., `{,` is not equal to `{`. Add space after element `{`. This solves your first problem.
2. As you are removing and adding `select` options dynamically in function `updateTextArea()`. You have to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handler for dynamically created elements.

Try:

```
$( document ).on("change",".selector",function() {
  updateTextArea();
});
```

Instead of

```
$(".selector").change(function () {
    updateTextArea();
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/T4guG/5/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! This solved the "only can change the options once" problem. Now there's only the issue of making sure the dropdowns work around punctuation.

Comment: @Jeremy I didnt see any other problem in question? Can you put it clearly with example what you are trying to achieve?